# Structur Pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I know I for sure misunderstand how to use pointers again. So here is my code. Would be nice if you all can help me. The program is simple. You write values in a structure array and print them out. Even so it would be nice if someone could explain to me when to use double pointers and how to use them probably.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXA 3

typedef enum{
    FOOD,
    ART,
    OTHERS
}TKindOfArticle;

typedef struct{
    int number;
    char description[31+1];
    int sellingGrossPrice;
    int vat;
    int minimumStockLevel;
    TKindOfArticle kindOf;
}TArticle;

void readOneArticle(TArticle* arti);
int readMaxArticle(TArticle* arti[]);
void printfOneArticle(TArticle arti);
void printfMaxArticle(TArticle *arti[],int read);

int main()
{
    TArticle arti[MAXA];
    int howMany;
    howMany = readMaxArticle(&arti);
    printfMaxArticle(&arti,howMany);


    return 0;
}

void readOneArticle(TArticle* arti){
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(arti->number));
    printf("Descrip: ");
    scanf("%s", &(arti->description));
    printf("SellGrossPrice: ");
    scanf("%d",&(arti->sellingGrossPrice));
    printf("MinimumStock: ");
    scanf("%d",&(arti->minimumStockLevel));
    printf("Kind of article (0: Food, 1: Art, 2: Others): ");
    scanf("%d",&(arti->kindOf));

    if(arti->kindOf == FOOD){
        arti->vat= arti->sellingGrossPrice*1.1;
    } else if(arti->kindOf == ART){
        arti->vat= arti->sellingGrossPrice*1.13;
    }else if(arti->kindOf == OTHERS){
        arti->vat= arti->sellingGrossPrice*1.2;
    }
}

int readMaxArticle(TArticle* arti[]){
    int read;
    int i=0;

    printf("Max Elements (max. 3): ");
    scanf("%d",&read);
    
    if(read>MAXA){
        printf("Error");
    } else{
        for(i=0; i<read;i++){
            readOneArticle(arti[i]);
            printf("\n");
            printf("Number: %d\nDescrip.: %s\nSell Gross: %d\nVat: %d\nMin. Stock: %d\n",
           (*arti[i]).number,(*arti[i]).description,
           (*arti[i]).sellingGrossPrice,(*arti[i]).vat,(*arti[i]).minimumStockLevel);
        }

    }
    return read;
}

void printfOneArticle(TArticle arti){
    printf("Number: %d\nDescrip.: %s\nSell Gross: %d\nVat: %d\nMin. Stock: %d\n",
           arti.number,arti.description,
           arti.sellingGrossPrice,arti.vat,arti.minimumStockLevel);

    switch(arti.kindOf){
        case 0: printf("Kind: Food\n");
                break;
        case 1: printf("Kind: Art\n");
                break;
        case 2: printf("Kind: Others\n");
                break;
    }
}

void printfMaxArticle(TArticle *arti[],int read){
    if(read>MAXA){
    } else{
        for(int i=0; i<read;i++){
            printfOneArticle(*arti[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: compile the program you have lot of warnings and errors in the program

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of structures: `TArticle arti[MAXA];`
But when you call `readMaxArticle(&arti)` function you pass pointer to array of `TArticle`. `TArticle *arti[]` it reads like this - arti is array of pointers to TArticle. But you want to pass pointer to array of `TArticle`. It won't compile anyway.

> error: cannot convert 'TArticle (*)[3]' to 'TArticle**'

You might want to look at [how to read C declaration](https://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html) and if you want to practice visit [this](https://cdecl.org/) site.